# iframe downloads the html source instead of displaying it

Tags: html, angularjs, azure, iframe, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to embed an html file in a page.

I use the following code:

```
<iframe src="{{resource.previewUrl}}" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen height="700" width="100%" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" ></iframe>
```

The source I get through angular is the address to the index.html file which is in Azure blob storage:

```
_sc.resource.previewUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://portalxxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/path/to/index.html");
```

When I open the page, it downloads the index.html file to my computer instead of displaying it. How can I force it to display?

Comment: Most likely the content type of your index.html file is set as `application/octet-stream`. If that's the case, then please change its content type to `text/html` and then it should display fine.

Comment: content type is already set to text/html in the <head> of index.html as this

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

Comment: I don't think that would work. Blob's content type should be `text/html`.

Comment: Thanks, now I got what did you mean. You were right about that. I changed it and now it doesn't download it but displays it as plain text of the file. Still, it's a progress. Thanks again!

Comment: Can you share the actual URL of the blob?

Comment: It's not a personal project, so I can't, sorry. I changed the unzipping part of the code. If the file has an ".html" or ".htm" extension, I set blob.Properties.ContentType to "text/html". And it works now! Thanks for your help! Why didn't you answer the question but only comment? I want to mark your reply as an accepted solution.

Comment: I had answered similar question at least twice and now I am not able to find them :P. I was hoping to mark this question as duplicate (and hence didn't answer). Because I am not able to find those, let me include my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is because of the content-type property of the blob. If content-type property of a blob is not set explicitly, Azure Blob storage assigns `application/octet-stream`.

In your case because you're not setting this property, even for your HTML files, the content type is set as default value i.e. `application/octet-stream`. Because the browser (especially Chrome) does not understand how to deal with this content type, it downloads it instead of rendering it.

Changing the content type of the blob to `text/html` should fix the problem.

Comment: Also, set Content-Disposition to "inline", if you haven't already.